# Signing Apps In MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop, ssl-certificate, code-signing

I've created and installed all the required certificates as far as I can tell. If I look in the details of the certificates they are all valid.

I've set the config to release in monodevelop.

In the options of MonoDevelop, I've choosen "Sign the application bundle"

In Identity I've choose the "Mac Developer" certificate I created.

I've created a profile which matches the "Profile Bundle" in info.plist.

However, it can't be found by monodevelop in provision : "No matching profile found"

What am I missing?

Really hope somebody knows where I'm going wrong. I'm soooo close to finally getting this stupid app working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the Provisioning Profile that you created on Apple's Mac Developer site installed on your machine.

If you open Xcode's Organizer window and select the "Devices" tab at the top, there should be a list on the left-hand side of the window with items like:

```
Library
  Provisioning Profiles
  Software Images
  Device Logs
  Screenshots
```

Select "Provisioning Profiles".

At the bottom of the screen, you should see a 4 buttons: New, Import, Export (on the left), and Refresh (on the far right).

Click the Refresh button and it will query Apple's developer site and download all your Provisioning Profiles.

Comment: Perfect!!!!! It created a couple of missing certificates for some reason and now it all works. Thanks very much, I've been trying to work that out for 2 weeks.